# 20.04 Installer with Errno 5

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

Trying to install ubuntu 20.04 "desktop" on my laptop, its a couple years old, but not ancient.

Randomly when copying files, the installer crashes with Errno 5.

The sha1sum of downloaded ISO image matches.

A USB stick installer was created using Rufus 3.10 Portable.

The laptop boots successfully into the Ubuntu installer. The disk check it performs at the beginning reports no errors.

The laptop contains two hard drives, a 128GB SSD and a 500GB HDD. 
I have run badblocks on both of these and no errors were detected.

Both the hard drives are using GPT.

The 128GB is partitioned into:

1. 500 MB EFI
2. 127.5 GB ext 4 /

The 500GB is partioned into:

1. 492 GB ext4 /home
2. 8 GB swap

I have tried both a normal installation and a minimal installation, neither works.

I have also tried using the automatic install, with no custom partitioning onto both disks. Still doesn't work.

Is there something stupid I am doing or not doing? Or is my laptop just fubar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue, the filesystem.squashfs was not flashed correctly and the check performed at the beginning by the installer did not detect this.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the very same problem. It would be very helpful if you could tell me how you fixed it. I know this was 2 years ago, but I guess I have to hope you are still online on this site.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1218564)